# Pagination of large API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, pagination, cursor-position

I can't get the javascript to loop through a cursor API. My previous question went unanswered, and I've learned quite a bit about scope and callbacks, but my answer still eludes me. I desperately need help as I'm 30+ hours into getting my program to get to page 3 of this api.

Help me. You're my only hope.

```js
var url = "xxx";
pages = []
n = 0;

var success = function(item_array) {
  $.each(item_array, function(index, item_array) {
    var objects = item_array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < objects; i++) {
      var items = item_array[i].images;
      if (items.data.length > 0) {
        var img_url = "xxx/images/500_max/" + items.data[0].filename;
        console.log(item_array[i].sku, img_url);
      }
    }
  })
  cursor_next = item_array.meta.cursor.next;
  pages.push(cursor_next)
  console.log(pages)
  next_url = "xxx&page[cursor]=" + pages[n];
}

function get() {
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: success,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'xxx');
    }
  })
}
get()
  .then(function() {
    for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
      get(url = next_url)
    }
  })
```

Here's what I get for pagination information:

```
"meta": {
    "cursor": {
        "current": "61poYD9eaDkR",
        "prev": null,
        "next": "k7A5MLKe8q2P",
        "count": 10
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't really defined a specific problem. Does the api return a property with the next url in it or total pages or other pagination detail??

Comment: you need describe the question clear first.

Comment: Edited the question to show what I get for pagination information. I have to grab the "next:" cursor and place it in a URL to get the next page.